# Is it possible to use If condition with the object of JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jquery code->

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var countPos=0;
    var add_button=$('#add_position');
    var wrapper=$('#position_fields');
    window.console && console.log('Document ready called');
    $(add_button).click(function(event){
        // http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( countPos >=9 ) {
            alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
            return;
        }
        countPos++;
        window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
        $(wrapper).append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
        <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
        <input type="button" value="-" \
            onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
        <textarea  name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
        </div>');
       });
      });




</script>
```

In the above code, I want to add an if statement before $(add_button).click(function(event)[When the user will click on the add button this event function will work]. Now I want to add 'else' If this condition goes wrong. Is it possible to do it?

I have tried in this way->

```
 //here I add a If statement with this object
 if($(add_button).click(function(event))){
    // http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( countPos >=9 ) {
        alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
        return;
    }
    countPos++;
    window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
    $(wrapper).append(
        '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
    <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
    <input type="button" value="-" \
        onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
    <textarea  name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
    </div>');
   });
   else{
          '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
    <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
    <input type="button" value="-" \
        onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
    <textarea  name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
    </div>'

        }
```

But this code does not work. How can I go to my destination?

Comment: Can you explain what you're *trying* to by putting the `.click()` handler inside the `if`?  "If the user clicks otherwise do something else" doesn't make much sense in an event-driven application. You mention *"if this condition goes wrong"* - what's the condition?  Are you wanting to check if there is an `add_button`?

Comment: No sir, I do not want to check whether there is an add_button or not. I want to check if a user clicks on the add button then the function will generate two dynamic input fields. If the user does not click on the add button then I want also to show the same dynamic input field which I declared under the .click().@freedomn-m

Comment: So, why the else block is needed?. You may ask the question. I want to add some extra functionalities in the else block sir.

Comment: The issue is *when* should the code run that's for "if the user does not click".  They can't click instantly, so they may click the button after a minute, after 10 minutes.  At what point do you want to go "they haven't clicked, so I'll show the inputs"?

Comment: Yes sir, you got it. I want to create this fields when page loads and the click event doesn't create any. Is it possible to do sir?.@charlietfl

Comment: Looks like: on load show some inputs, when user clicks add another input.  Just remove the `if(..)` wrapper (keep the event), the `else{` (and corresponding `}`s and you'll have what you want.

Comment: Sir, I want to create these fields when the page loads and the click event doesn't create any instantly. If the user clicks on the add button then it works like whatever it does normally@freedomn-m.

Comment: Yes, sir, You got where I want to go..@freedomn-m

Comment: Ok,Sir, I capture it. Now, I am going to try. Thank you for your facilitation.@freedomn-m

Comment: Sir, I have faced another problem. How can I remove the wrapper when the user clicks add another input. This wrapper exists under the $(add_button).click(function(event) that means everything will work when the user clicks.@freedomn-m

Comment: How can I create these input fields when the page loads?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and call the function on page load and in the click event handler